# Word VBA Removing page numbers of only appendix

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to remove page numbers in my document only if it is in an Appendix Section.  Is there a way to modify the code below with an IF statement to check if the Section is an Appendix style and then execute?

```
Sub DeletePageNumbers()

Dim objSect As Section 
Dim objHF As HeaderFooter 
Dim objPNum As PageNumber

For Each objSect In ActiveDocument.Sections

   For Each objHF In objSect.Headers 
       For Each objPNum In objHF.PageNumbers 
           objPNum.Delete 

       Next 
   Next

   For Each objHF In objSect.Footers 
       For Each objPNum In objHF.PageNumbers 
       objPNum.Delete 

       Next 
   Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you plan to tell if the page is an Appendix page? By it being the last page?

Comment: It should have a defined Style of "Appendix 1"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  See Code Below

```
    For Each objSect In ActiveDocument.Sections

    If objSect.Range.Paragraphs(1).Style = "Appendix 1" Then

         For Each objHF In objSect.Footers
             For Each objPNum In objHF.PageNumbers
                  objPNum.Delete

             Next
         Next
   End If

   Next
```